# How to stop direct accessing a page without login in using Tapastry

Tags: jsp, tapestry

**( 1.)**
I have a `Login` page and a `Index` page in Tapestry. I check the user name and password and direct the page into index page using following method.

```
Object onSuccess(){
       return Index.class;
}
```

But if i use the simple URL directly to index page still it goes there. how to make it only accessible though Login page.

**( 2.)**
how to pass a parameter between pages?. If i can pass `user_id` or generated key between pagers then i can give an error if some one loads the page without that key. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do session management.

Or other solution is you can pass parameter user_id to Index from Login as

From Login onPassivate() method pass this parameter and in Index define parameter with that name and in onActivate() get this value.